# Limiting the current output of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, oscillator, current-limiting

I'm trying to charge a high-voltage capacitor bank with a battery. My design uses an oscillator plus op-amp connected to a transformer that feeds into a bridge rectifier.

The issue is that the current draw on the primary side of the transformer is crazy high due to what is essentially a short on the secondary side. I don't know how to fix this without throwing a 500 MΩ in series with the cap bank and having a terrible cap charging rate. Do you have any ideas on how I should go about solving this?

Here's my current design. I still have to increase the frequency from my oscillator (my target is 10 kHz), so it isn't entirely accurate, but it should explain what I'm going for.

[image: My design]

Of note: This is my first big project, so my design might be terrible. I'd appreciate it if you let me know if you find something else that is obviously terrible.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the op amp not being able to output *enough* current for this.

Comment: Hmm, my understanding might be fundamentally wrong. I was under the assumption that the current draw would skyrocket with such a low impedance and immediately burn out the op amp

Comment: It might. My main concern is that limiting the current to something safe for the average op amp means limiting to tens of milliamps, which doesn't seem very practical for your purposes.

Comment: A capacitor between the output of U1 and the primary coil L1 would help a lot. Is there a special reason why you don't use a flyback converter topology?

Comment: 1N4007 are not the kind of diodes you want.  Those are power diodes, meant for 50/60Hz applications.  Very slow.   You want a fast recovery diode, i.e. schottky etc...

Comment: Have you considered using a power transistor in place of the op-amp? You could deliver more power to the primary winding and even limit the current using a series resistor on the primary side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: big capacitors charged to high voltages are quite deadly. If you kill yourself, don't sue me.

Opamps generally aren't for high power. They're for processing and amplifying analog signals. And in this case, by "amplification" we mean to amplify a low voltage or a current to bring it to a more usable level, for example to be acquired by a microcontroller ADC or do something with it. But opamps usually are not about the other meaning of "amplification" which is to take a low power signal and output a high power version (preferably with efficiency). In this case we call them "power amplifiers" to make the difference clear.

In this case, you don't need an analog amplifier either, because the signal you want is a square wave. And the simplest, most efficient way to make a high power square wave is with power switches (ie, MOSFETs).

So, here's an example:

[image]

So you get a pair of fast MOSFETs with low RdsON, and a 50c [FET driver](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp5901-d.pdf). Now you can make a 12V square wave with pretty high current, 10A would be realistic, without unreasonable losses.

Then I put a cap in series with the transformer. It should be a high current film cap, the kind used in induction cookers. That makes it a resonant converter, but the main feature of the cap is that if the top MOSFET gets stuck in the "ON" state due to something happening while messing with the circuit, the cap will charge, and then no more current will flow. So you get automatic overcurrent protection on your MOSFETs. It will only transfer power if it is fed a square wave signal.

Output diodes should be high speed, maybe UF4007 or something.

Frequency can easily go to 100-200k with these drivers, if the FETs are properly sized.

Capacitor value should be chosen such that the resonant freqeuency of the cap and transformer inductance is just a bit above the frequency you'll use. Or pick a cap and then adjust the frequency to get a nice sine wave current in the transformer. Normally a resonant converter would need a bit more logistics, for example a microcontroller that will adjust the frequency according to the current in the MOSFETs, to avoid exceeding the safe limit while pumping maximum power in the output.

Basically, 1000µF charged to 650V is 211 Joules. That's enough energy to vaporize the tip of the multimeter probe and rain molten metal on your safety glasses. It will also make a nice fibrillator (it's the opposite of a defibrillator).

To output 211 joules in a reasonable time (say 5 seconds) we need 40 watts, so a reasonable input current of 5-6 amps on the 12V side, accounting for losses.

The transformer should be chosen not to saturate with this current. If it saturates, current spikes in the MOSFETs will become unreasonably high, and they will smoke.

Note this is not a beginner-friendly circuit. The output voltage is deadly, and all components on the low voltage side may burst into flames if it's not done right. For example if the layout is bad and the MOSFETs oscillate, they'll smoke. The thing can also turn into a wideband radio jammer.

Comment: Wow this is an excellent answer, very funny and informative. I think I might knock the output voltage down a little bit. I'm not exactly a beginner but as you can tell, I'm probably not quite ready to deal with this high power yet. 

Quick question: by the inductance of transformer you mean the mutual inductance, right?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a turns ratio of sqrt(500mH/160uH) = 55.9, and are charging the capacitor to about 55.9 x 12V = 670V.

The capacitor is 1mF.  It will take 670V x 1mF = 670mC to complete charging.

For an ordinary op amp that might output 20mA of current on the primary side and a 55.9 turns ratio you will get 20mA / 55.9 = 357uA of current on the secondary side.

The total time to charge would then be 670mC / 357uA = 31.27 minutes.

So unless this is a special op-amp that can output a lot of current, charging is going to take a long time regardless.

You first need to increase the output of the op-amp and then worry about current limiting.

1. I would recommend putting a capacitor in series with L1.  Otherwise L1 will see a DC voltage and DC current will build up that doesn't contribute to charging your capacitor.
2. Put an inductor (like 1mH) in series with L1.  The impedance would be 2*pi*10kHz*1mH = 62.8 ohms @ 10kHz.  So, it should limit the current to be no more than 190mA @ 12V, but probably less factoring in the capacitor if you use it.

Comment: The opamp wrongly has its +input at 0V instead of at half the supply voltage then it might not work. Of course the opamp must be a power amplifier instead. The power amplifier also must have its input correctly biased.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that the current draw on the primary side of the transformer is crazy high due to what is essentially a short on the secondary side.

Assuming that the transformer and the operating frequency are scaled correctly for the application, the op-amp provides all the output current limiting you'll need. Most op-amps that aren't power op-amps nor line drivers will supply a couple tens of mA into a short. So you got that already.

If you insist on using an op-amp for this application, you'll want to use a power op-amp or even an audio amplifier. All of them usually have output current limiting and thermal protection - so as long as the transformer can take it, you're OK.

It's not hard to make an LM386 oscillate. It'll push >0.5W into the transformer primary, and it's a one-chip solution. Try it!

"Back in the day", the transformer primary would be driven from a 2-transistor multivibrator with a push-pull power stage. Four transistors, a couple passive parts, done. I've made a few of those until I've ran into the world of purposefully-oscillating audio amplifiers. They are damn simple to use for this, usually. Not the best  power conversion efficiency, but they can provide quite a low harmonic content and the solution will be EMC-friendly. And you can usually find one with exactly the power rating you need, as long as you can dissipate the heat.